# Using moment to calculate time difference

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, momentjs

I am using below logic to `calculate the time difference`.

However, this is giving wrong result value when `days > 1`.
Please help simplifying the code.

I will be using the time difference logic in angular framework.

```
const startDate = new Date(form.value.startDate);
const endDate = new Date();
const dateDiff = this.calculateDateDifference(startDate, endDate);

calculateDateDifference(startDate, endDate) {
    const difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    const seconds = Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    const days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    console.log(days + ' days ' + hours + ' hours ' + minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds');
    if (days > 1) {
        return `${days} Days, ${hours} Hours, ${minutes} Mins`;
    } else {
        return `${hours} Hours, ${minutes} Mins`;
    }
}
```

**How can I achieve the same output using "moment"?**

Comment: You should avoid Moment, especially with Angular: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ Can you create and provide a [mcve] of the problem? I recommend to fix it with native functions.

Comment: The documentation shows comparison with Luxon. should I use Luxon instead?

Comment: Why do you need a third-party library for this simple task? Fix the calculation. What's the problem with the given code? Don't just add cool libraries because it's fancy. Your users have to download these libraries.

Comment: It definitely makes sense what you are talking about.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by **jabaa**, you should avoid moment.js as it is now in a maintenance state.

You can try out [day.js](https://day.js.org/) which is a modern equivalent and won't require a lot of effort to modify your code.

You can install it via yarn/npm with the package name `dayjs`

You can then write something like:

```js
const startDate = new Date("2024-03-18")
const endDate = new Date("2024-03-18 17:00");
console.log(calculateDateDifference(startDate, endDate))

const startDate2 = new Date("2024-03-10")
const endDate2 = new Date();
console.log(calculateDateDifference(startDate2, endDate2))

function calculateDateDifference(startDate, endDate) {
    const difference = dayjs(endDate).diff(startDate, 'millisecond');

    const seconds = Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    const days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    if (days > 1) {
        return `${days} Days, ${hours} Hours, ${minutes} Mins`;
    } else {
        return `${hours} Hours, ${minutes} Mins`;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

I appreciate you mentioned angular, to allow the running on Stackoverflow I just used plain JS and HTML, but this should work on Angular also.

Comment: What's the advantage of your code? It's doesn't reduce the code length or complexity. Does it fix the problem mentioned in the question? How do you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I hope it helps.

you can use "[Subtract](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)".

```
var dateA = moment("2024-03-19")
var dateB = moment("2024-03-20")
var millisecondsDiff = dateA.subtract(dateB.valueOf(), 'milliseconds')
```

this way you can get the value of the difference between two dates with Moment.js

Comment: You didn't solve the problem mentioned in the question.

Comment: I showed you how to get not only the difference in hours but also in milliseconds. I don't understand your comment, could you be more specific please?

Comment: The OP already gets the difference in seconds. I don't understand how your answer could help. It doesn't reduce the code length or complexity and it doesn't solve the problem mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
const moment = require('moment');

function calculateDateDifference(startDate, endDate) {
    const duration = moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate));

    const days = duration.days();
    const hours = duration.hours();
    const minutes = duration.minutes();
    const seconds = duration.seconds();

    console.log(`${days} days ${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${seconds} seconds`);
    
    if (days > 1) {
        return `${days} Days, ${hours} Hours, ${minutes} Mins`;
    } else {
        return `${hours} Hours, ${minutes} Mins`;
    }
}

const startDate = moment(form.value.startDate);
const endDate = moment();
const dateDiff = calculateDateDifference(startDate, endDate);
```

**maybe it is useful for you I converted that code in the moment**

Comment: You didn't solve the problem mentioned in the question.